# How to use class objects properly

Tags: visual-c++

I'm unable to compare (list[0].getOwned() == false) 
I'm also unable to actually change the data with (list[0].setOwned(true);)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;


class Weapon
{
private:
    bool owned; // bool for item owned
    string item; // string for Item 1
    string sound; // string for Sound

public:
    Weapon(bool O, string I, string S)
    {
        bool owned = O;
        string item = I; 
        string  sound = S;
    }
    Weapon()
    {
        bool owned = false;
        string item = "no name";
        string sound = "no name";

    }
    void setOwned(bool O)
    {
        owned = O;
    }

    void setItem(string I)
    {
        item = I;
    }

    void setSound(string S)
    {
        sound = S;
    }

    bool getOwned()
    {
        return owned;
    }

    string getItem()
    {
        return item;
    }

    string getSound()
    {
        return sound;
    }

};

int main()
{
    const int NUM_WEAPONS = 5;
    Weapon list[NUM_WEAPONS];
    list[0] = Weapon(false,"Sword", "Shing");
    list[1] = Weapon(false, "Axe", "Fwump");
    list[2] = Weapon(false, "Dagger", "Tsk");
    list[3] = Weapon(false, "Tiger Mount", "Roar");
    list[4] = Weapon(false, "Shield", "Thud");

  if (list[0].getOwned() == false)
{
   cout << "You've purchased a Sword" << endl;
   list[0].setOwned(true);
    cash = cash - p1;

}
else if (list[0].getOwned() == true)
{
    cout << "You already own this weapon" << endl;
}

}
```

I expect the list[0].getOwned() == false to compare and pass through the if statement to then set it to true so you cant "buy it again".
what it does is nothing, am I using the class objects incorrectly or am I missing something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

`Weapon` constructor declares and initializes a local variable named `owned`. It does not initialize member variable `this->owned`. Your program then exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing uninitialized object.